# GDB (intel) : print works but not info address

Tags: fortran, gdb, intel-fortran

The tree is as follows

```
module M
    type A
      real     , allocatable :: dd (:)
    end type A


    type B 
      type (A) , pointer :: aa
    end type B


    type C
     type(B) , pointer :: bb
    end type C

    type(C) , allocatable :: cc(:)

end module M
```

In gdb:

```
print M::cc(10) % bb % aa % dd(100) 
$1 = 0
```

However,

```
info address M::cc(10) % bb % aa % dd (100)
```

generates the error: No symbol "cc(10) % bb % aa% dd (100)" in current context.

```
whatis address M::cc(10) % bb % aa% dd(100)
```

generates the error: Cannot access memory at address 0xa0

I see that the compiler flag "-g" has to be specified to access global variables but that didn't help.

The reason I need the address is to `watch M::cc(10) %bb % aa % dd (100)` with a software watchpoint so that I don't slow gdb drastically. I'm hoping that this would give me insight into the lines of code which change the value of `dd (100)`.

One option that I've already explored is to just go ahead and set the watch point with:

```
watch cc(10) % bb % aa % dd ( 100 )
```

But this results in several hundred watchpoints with Numbers 1.1 , 1.2, 1.3 .... 1.500! This is really slowing down the execution in gdb.

So how could I access the address? If that is not possible, what is the best alternative?

Comment: It is an allocatable @RodrigoRodrigues and not a typo.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues edited now, I see the confusion. It is indeed d(:)

Comment: @chw21 edited post

Comment: Though not related to gdb, does it possibly change the result if the pointer is defaulted to null as "type (A) , pointer :: aa => null()" (and similar to bb) in the type definition?